# Servlet using RESTLET with xml as input from html

Tags: java, xml, restlet

I am new to restlet development. I want to develop an application using restlet which takes input as xml and returns xml as response.

I could not find it on official RESTLET website. Please someone guide how to proceed on this.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Can [this](http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/How-to-Fetch-Request-XML-in-Java-Restlet-td2604499.html) be of any help ?

Comment: There are various ways to process XML in Restlet Framework, depending on your project characteristics. SAX / DOM / Bean serialization via Jackson, JAXB and JiBX, etc. Can you detail what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with RESTLET, but according to their documentation page here: http://restlet.com/learn/tutorial/2.2/#part03
it is really easy to get `XML` in and out. `XML` is a simple `String` which follows some conventions. In the get method, just receive `xml` as String, parse it (ie. with `SAXParser`), get necessary information. And return value should also be String. Just make the `XML` String yourself and return it from the `@Get` annotated method as in example.